# EXEC args (value) with quotes on linux from Ant script

Tags: ant

bash shell:

```
./mimic_cmd "startDaemon()"
```

Corresponding Ant code:

```
 <exec failonerror="true" executable="/bin/mimic_cmd">
    <arg value='"startDaemon()"' />
 </exec>
```

1. Does the Ant code exactly represent the above command at the bash shell? Based on the debug info, it looks like it:

> ```
>  [exec] Executing '/bin/mimic_cmd' with arguments:
>  [exec] '"startDaemon()"'
>  [exec] 
>  [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
>  [exec] not part of the command.
>  Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing '/bin/mimic_cmd' with arguments:
>  '"startDaemon()"'
>  The ' characters around the executable and arguments are not part of the command.
> ```

However, the Ant code returns and exit code of 1 while the Bash shell command returns 0.

Toggling vmlauncher doesn't help, and paths are all correct.

The same Ant code works on windows with the resulting debug output:

> ```
>  [exec] Executing 'C:\bin\mimic_cmd' with arguments:
>  [exec] '"startDaemon()"'
>  [exec] 
>  [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
>  [exec] not part of the command.
>  Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\bin\mimic_cmd' with arguments:
>  '"startDaemon()"'
>  The ' characters around the executable and arguments are not part of the command.
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you tell us what `mimic_cmd` is? (Is it an ELF executable, is it a script -- and if so, what is its contents?)

You **don't need nor want the double-quotes** inside your ANT XML attributes (incidentally, for it to be well-formed XML you should have written them as `&quot;` not `"`, but that changes nothing with respect to this discussion) unless your executable expects them.  The corresponding ANT code for either of the following (100% equivalent) shell command lines:

```
   ./mimic_cmd "startDaemon()"
   ./mimic_cmd 'startDaemon()'
   ./mimic_cmd startDaemon\(\)
   ./mimic_cmd startDaemon"()"
   ./mimic_cmd startDaemon'()'
```

...actually is:

```
   <exec failonerror="true" executable="/bin/mimic_cmd"> 
      <arg value="startDaemon()" /> 
   </exec>
```

...or, for illustrative purposes:

```
   <!-- spawn a shell with your original command line -->
   <exec failonerror="true" executable="/bin/sh"> 
      <arg value="-c" /> 
      <arg value="/bin/mimic_cmd &quot;startDaemon()&quot;" /> 
   </exec>
```

Why that is so is longwinded to explain; suffices to say that, in your specific case, the only time when you'd have to use double quotes would be when ultimately issuing the command via a *nix shell (either interactively or as part of another script or programatically via the `exec`ing of `sh -c`), and only in order for that shell not to think that the round parens `()` have special meaning.  By the time the shell would in turn spawn `mimic_cmd` it would have already stripped the double quotes (and substituted backslash-escaped sequences etc. -- see [how a *nix shell parses its command line](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html))  ANT does not run your command via the shell but rather executes it directly, so in this case `mimic_cmd` finds itself with a bunch of double quotes on its hand which it apparently doesn't know how to handle.

You essentially have to think of it as replacing all forms of shell quoting and escaping with XML escaping and breaing down into `<arg/>` tags.

Windows' `CMD.EXE` is [special](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Olympics) in the sense that, unline *nix shells, it does minimal parsing (and generally does not care about double quotes in program arguments), leaving it up to the program to figure out what you meant by quoting.  (This is actually a hard limitation of Windows' [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) which [does not have the notion of `argv[]`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175986), leaving it up to each program to intepret `lpCommandLine` in whichever way it sees fit; some will get rid of the quotes for you, but that behaviour is extremely inconsistent, e.g. issue `echo "bla"` on the `CMD.EXE` prompt to see what `CMD.EXE`'s builtins think about quoting.)  Again, in your case the round parens `()` have no meaning for `CMD.EXE` so you don't need them even when typing the command at a command prompt.  As for ANT, on Windows as on *nix platforms, it spwans `mimic_cmd` via `CreateProcess` not `CMD.EXE` so you don't really want to quote anything.

Comment: mimic_cmd is a shell executable for a cross platform installation solution. I don't work on the in-house team that develops it, so honestly I can't say whether the quotes are always needed, but some commands appear to need them or must have a space before the parenthesis?

'mimic_cmd StartDaemon()' does work in ANT and on the command line (no quotes, no space)

'mimic_cmd createNewWorkspace(blah)' without quotes does not work at all; '"mimic_cmd createNewWorkspace(blah)"' works on Windows, but not linux, and 'mimic_cmd createNewWorkSpace (blah)' works on both... (space before parenthesis)

Comment: Hmm... careful with those round parens without quotes on *nix, they are probably doing something behind your back you don't expect... does typing `/bin/mimic_cmd "createNewWorkspace(blah)"` work on a *nix command line? If so, `<exec failonerror="true" executable="/bin/mimic_cmd"><arg value="createNewWorkspace(blah)" /></exec>` should work just as well in ANT. If `blah` is itself a string it'd get more interesting: `/bin/mimic_cmd "createNewWorkspace(\"blah\")"` or `/bin/mimic_cmd 'createNewWorkspace("blah")'` in a shell or, in ANT, `...<arg value="createNewWorkspace(&quot;blah&quot;)" />...`